# C++ Seeking with CreateFile instead of fopen

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, fread, fseek

I would like to exchange FILE* with HANDLE=CreateFile() to test the speed difference.

I am trying to change my code now.

Could somebody tell me how I chould change these 2 lines to reflect that I am dealing with a handle now and not a FILE* anymore?

```
fseek(myFile,iBytePos,SEEK_SET);
fread(&SomeValues[0],iByteCount,1,myFile);
```

I tried

```
LARGE_INTEGER l;

l.QuadPart=iBytePos;
SetFilePointer(myFile,l.LowPart,&l.HighPart,FILE_BEGIN);

DWORD dw;
BOOL result = ReadFile(myFile,&SomeValues[0],iByteCount,&dw,NULL);
```

but something is not correct. I must have gone wrong somewhere.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows API equivalent for `fread` is [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) and for `fseek` is [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx). If you merely replace those calls the performance difference will be slim, if any. In contrast to `fseek`, `SetFilePointer` supports files > 2GB. If you don't need that the call is simply:

```
SetFilePointer(myFile, iBytePos, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```

You can speed up disk I/O using the Windows API by exploiting its greater flexibility. If you have lots of seek-read-seek-read operations you might benefit from using [`ReadFileScatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365469.aspx) instead.

Another potential route for optimization would be to use Asynchronous I/O. A comparison can be found at [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

For `fseek` you can use `SetFilePointerEx` or `SetFilePointer`.

For `fread` you can use `ReadFile` or `ReadFileEX`

You can find help here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: While it is possible to use the *Ex versions of the Windows API calls they provide functionality beyond what the C Runtime calls offer. The plain calls more closely resemble the C Runtime calls.